# ASP.NET MVC Override HandleError causes View to not render

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, onerror, handleerror

In my app I'm using "HandleError" whereby if an error happens, my "Error.vbhtml" view renders. This is working great, except now I want to also log the error.  I've built a custom HandleError Class, Inherited the HandleErrorAttribute, and Overridden the OnException method.

Now my error gets logged, but the Error.vbhtml view doesn't get rendered... what praytell am I messing?

```
Imports System.Web.Mvc

Namespace Mvc.Attributes
    Public Class HandleError : Inherits System.Web.Mvc.HandleErrorAttribute
        Private ExceptionService As Domain.IExceptionService
        Public Sub New()
            ExceptionService = New Domain.ExceptionService(New Domain.ExceptionRepository)
        End Sub

        Public Overrides Sub OnException(ByVal exceptionContext As ExceptionContext)
            ''# Log the exception if it has not been handled elsewhere
            If Not exceptionContext.ExceptionHandled Then
                ExceptionService.AddException(exceptionContext.Exception)
                ExceptionService.SubmitChanges()
                ''# Signal to the system that we've handled the exception
                exceptionContext.ExceptionHandled = True
            End If
        End Sub
    End Class
End Namespace
```

Comment: Try calling `base.OnException()` after you are done logging? [shot-in-the-dark], Also `HandleError` isn't the best name choice ever.  Attributes should always end the name with the word `Attribute` and probably not share names with the class they inherit (even though they are in a different namespace).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just took a look at the source code of the HandleError method at Codeplex.  I scooped some of the code from there

```
        Dim controllerName As String = DirectCast(filterContext.RouteData.Values("controller"), String)
        Dim actionName As String = DirectCast(filterContext.RouteData.Values("action"), String)
        Dim model As New HandleErrorInfo(filterContext.Exception, controllerName, actionName)
        filterContext.Result = New ViewResult() With { _
         .ViewName = View, _
         .MasterName = Master, _
         .ViewData = New ViewDataDictionary(Of HandleErrorInfo)(model), _
         .TempData = filterContext.Controller.TempData _
        }
        filterContext.ExceptionHandled = True
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Clear()
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 500

        ''# Certain versions of IIS will sometimes use their own error page when
        ''# they detect a server error. Setting this property indicates that we
        ''# want it to try to render ASP.NET MVC's error page instead.
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = True
```

This appears to work